# Passing JSON data from a function, from an API to a screen

Tags: json, flutter, dart, class

I am taking a flutter course and I am trying to understand API'S and passing data between screens and from the actual JSON data. I am trying to make the simplest weather app possible but can't get my data from my function to the screen. All the tutorials are either passing to different pages or doing other things that take away from me actually learning how to do it on the most simple level.

Here is my code, if you could show me how I get the JSON data I have in the GetWeatherModel it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code, I am able to print to the console but cant get any further without copy and pasting code and not knowing what I am doing.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

//Create some const's for the API key and the openweather url. If i put this in
//the weather class it needs to be static, why is this?
const openWeatherMapURL = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather';
const apiKey = '9afee6d05ce90e00ea3e3372128de9b6';

class WeatherPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const WeatherPage({super.key, this.locationWeather});

  final locationWeather;

  @override
  State<WeatherPage> createState() => _WeatherPageState();
}

class _WeatherPageState extends State<WeatherPage> {
  GetWeatherModel getWeatherModel = GetWeatherModel();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getWeatherModel.getLocationWeather();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My first weather app'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text('stuff'),
              Text(
                'Temperature',
              ),
              Text(
                'Description',
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      GetWeatherModel getWeather = GetWeatherModel();
                      getWeather.getLocationWeather();
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text('Get Data'))
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class Location {
  //Create two variables to store the longitude and latitude retrieved
  //from geo locator
  double? latitude;
  double? longitude;

  //Create a function to retrieve the longitude and latitude from geolocator
  Future<void> getCurrentLocation() async {
    //Get the user permission to use location
    await Geolocator.requestPermission();
    try {
      //try to get the current location from the phone through the
      //geolocator package with low accuracy to save battery and it is just
      //the general area needed
      Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
          desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low);

      //put the latitude and longitude of the current position into these variabls

      latitude = position.latitude;
      longitude = position.longitude;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      //throw ('Location cannot be found');
    }
  }
}

class GetWeatherModel {
  //Create a function that uses the getCurrentLocation function and uses
//it to retrieve data from the open weather api
  Future<dynamic> getLocationWeather() async {
    Location location = Location();
    await location.getCurrentLocation();
    // print(location.longitude);
    // print(location.latitude);
    http.Response response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(
        "$openWeatherMapURL?lat=${location.latitude}&lon=${location.longitude}&appid=$apiKey&units=metric",
      ),
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      String data = response.body;

      // The decodedData variable needs to be a var because it is a dynamic data type,
      // and we wont know what the type is until it is returned
      var decodedData = jsonDecode(data);

      return decodedData;
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }
  }

// Try to make the variable below more explicit by giving them the
//type that will be returned
// String weatherDescription = decodedData['weather'][0]['description'];
// double temperature = decodedData['main']['temp'];
// String cityName = decodedData['name'];
// double condition = decodedData['weather'][0]['id'];
// print(weatherDescription);
// print(temperature);
// print(cityName);
// print(condition);
// return weatherDescription;
//return decodedData;

//weather[0].description - from json viewer awesome path copy
// main.temp
// name
// weather[0].id
//print(decodedData);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First of all, I think you misunderstood the differences between class and methods. You don't need such kind of classes; GetWeatherModel, or Location. Basically, you can declare your methods inside of stateless/stateful widgets.
2. Secondly, The purpose of creating a class model from JSON is to transform JSON data into a format that is understandable and processable by a programming language. JSON data is a text-based data format, and by creating a class model, this data becomes usable within a programming language. So you should model your JSON that your API response.
3. For JSON modeling purposes, first, you should call your API at platforms like Postman. Then grab your JSON response and paste it into this perfect application; https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/ this will automatically create a model (For advanced usage you can use an extension like https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable but I suggest you use above web application as you are beginner)
4. I have created WeatherModel for you;

```
        class WeatherModel {
          Coord? coord;
          List? weather;
          String? base;
          Main? main;
          int? visibility;
          Wind? wind;
          Clouds? clouds;
          int? dt;
          Sys? sys;
          int? timezone;
          int? id;
          String? name;
          int? cod;
        
          WeatherModel(
              {this.coord,
              this.weather,
              this.base,
              this.main,
              this.visibility,
              this.wind,
              this.clouds,
              this.dt,
              this.sys,
              this.timezone,
              this.id,
              this.name,
              this.cod});
        
          WeatherModel.fromJson(Map json) {
            coord = json['coord'] != null ? new Coord.fromJson(json['coord']) : null;
            if (json['weather'] != null) {
              weather = [];
              json['weather'].forEach((v) {
                weather!.add(new Weather.fromJson(v));
              });
            }
            base = json['base'];
            main = json['main'] != null ? new Main.fromJson(json['main']) : null;
            visibility = json['visibility'];
            wind = json['wind'] != null ? new Wind.fromJson(json['wind']) : null;
            clouds =
                json['clouds'] != null ? new Clouds.fromJson(json['clouds']) : null;
            dt = json['dt'];
            sys = json['sys'] != null ? new Sys.fromJson(json['sys']) : null;
            timezone = json['timezone'];
            id = json['id'];
            name = json['name'];
            cod = json['cod'];
          }
        
          Map toJson() {
            final Map data = new Map();
            if (this.coord != null) {
              data['coord'] = this.coord!.toJson();
            }
            if (this.weather != null) {
              data['weather'] = this.weather!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
            }
            data['base'] = this.base;
            if (this.main != null) {
              data['main'] = this.main!.toJson();
            }
            data['visibility'] = this.visibility;
            if (this.wind != null) {
              data['wind'] = this.wind!.toJson();
            }
            if (this.clouds != null) {
              data['clouds'] = this.clouds!.toJson();
            }
            data['dt'] = this.dt;
            if (this.sys != null) {
              data['sys'] = this.sys!.toJson();
            }
            data['timezone'] = this.timezone;
            data['id'] = this.id;
            data['name'] = this.name;
            data['cod'] = this.cod;
            return data;
          }
        }
    class Coord {
          double? lon;
          double? lat;
        
          Coord({this.lon, this.lat});
        
          Coord.fromJson(Map json) {
            lon = json['lon'];
            lat = json['lat'];
          }
        
          Map toJson() {
            final Map data = new Map();
            data['lon'] = this.lon;
            data['lat'] = this.lat;
            return data;
          }
        }
        
        class Weather {
          int? id;
          String? main;
          String? description;
          String? icon;
        
          Weather({this.id, this.main, this.description, this.icon});
        
          Weather.fromJson(Map json) {
            id = json['id'];
            main = json['main'];
            description = json['description'];
            icon = json['icon'];
          }
        
          Map toJson() {
            final Map data = new Map();
            data['id'] = this.id;
            data['main'] = this.main;
            data['description'] = this.description;
            data['icon'] = this.icon;
            return data;
          }
        }
        
        class Main {
          double? temp;
          double? feelsLike;
          double? tempMin;
          double? tempMax;
          int? pressure;
          int? humidity;
        
          Main(
              {this.temp,
              this.feelsLike,
              this.tempMin,
              this.tempMax,
              this.pressure,
              this.humidity});
        
          Main.fromJson(Map json) {
            temp = json['temp'];
            feelsLike = json['feels_like'];
            tempMin = json['temp_min'];
            tempMax = json['temp_max'];
            pressure = json['pressure'];
            humidity = json['humidity'];
          }
        
          Map toJson() {
            final Map data = new Map();
            data['temp'] = this.temp;
            data['feels_like'] = this.feelsLike;
            data['temp_min'] = this.tempMin;
            data['temp_max'] = this.tempMax;
            data['pressure'] = this.pressure;
            data['humidity'] = this.humidity;
            return data;
          }
        }
        
        class Wind {
          double? speed;
          int? deg;
          double? gust;
        
          Wind({this.speed, this.deg, this.gust});
        
          Wind.fromJson(Map json) {
            speed = json['speed'];
            deg = json['deg'];
            gust = json['gust'];
          }
        
          Map toJson() {
            final Map data = new Map();
            data['speed'] = this.speed;
            data['deg'] = this.deg;
            data['gust'] = this.gust;
            return data;
          }
        }
        
        class Clouds {
          int? all;
        
          Clouds({this.all});
        
          Clouds.fromJson(Map json) {
            all = json['all'];
          }
        
          Map toJson() {
            final Map data = new Map();
            data['all'] = this.all;
            return data;
          }
        }
        
        class Sys {
          int? type;
          int? id;
          String? country;
          int? sunrise;
          int? sunset;
        
          Sys({this.type, this.id, this.country, this.sunrise, this.sunset});
        
          Sys.fromJson(Map json) {
            type = json['type'];
            id = json['id'];
            country = json['country'];
            sunrise = json['sunrise'];
            sunset = json['sunset'];
          }
        
          Map toJson() {
            final Map data = new Map();
            data['type'] = this.type;
            data['id'] = this.id;
            data['country'] = this.country;
            data['sunrise'] = this.sunrise;
            data['sunset'] = this.sunset;
            return data;
          }
        }
```

and here the other codes that calling API and modelling JSON;

```
const openWeatherMapURL = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather';
const apiKey = '9afee6d05ce90e00ea3e3372128de9b6';

class WeatherPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const WeatherPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<WeatherPage> createState() => _WeatherPageState();
}

class _WeatherPageState extends State<WeatherPage> {
  WeatherModel _weatherModel = WeatherModel();

  Future<WeatherModel> getLocationWeather() async {
    try {
      http.Response response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse(
          "$openWeatherMapURL?lat=40.741895&lon=-73.989308&appid=$apiKey&units=metric",
        ),
      );
      return WeatherModel.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    } catch (e) {
      print('$e');
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My first weather app'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                'City: ${_weatherModel.name}',
              ),
              Text(
                'Temperature: ${_weatherModel.main?.temp}',
              ),
              Text(
                'Temperature Max: ${_weatherModel.main?.tempMax}',
              ),
              Text(
                'Temperature Max: ${_weatherModel.main?.tempMin}',
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    getLocationWeather().then((value) {
                      setState(() {
                        _weatherModel = value;
                      });

                    });
                  },
                  child: Text('Get Data'))
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Hope this helps. Good luck :)

Comment: That's an amazing response, thank you. Your right, I am unsure of the difference between all the different types of code and when to use them at the moment. It helps me to be able to look through code like that and see what is being done. It will take some time for me to understand it correctly and be able to repeat it but that was an amazing response so thank you. I do want to stay away from things like postman at the moment because it really does help me to understand it with just raw dart code. Thanks again and good look to you too!